# Почему я не могу стрелками выбрать нужный тег / атрибут в редакторе кода Atom?

Tags: atom

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Почему я не могу стрелками выбрать нужный мне тег / атрибут при помощи стрелки на вниз?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавь скрин keymap файла у меня такая же проблема была - решил

Comment: @midia вот,смотри

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сотри первую зеленую строку(для ответа нужно 30 символов)

Comment: Спасибо, заработало. Не знаешь какой - нибудь хороший autocomplete js в Atom?

Comment: Из-за отсутствия autocomplete js в Atom(по крайней мере я не нашел) я и перешел на brackets:). А если хотите поблагодарить, по правилам сайта,можете либо кликнуть стрелочку вверх слева от ответа либо принять ответ на вопрос поставив галочку.